# Writing Joomla bridge with User_profiles table plugin

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6

I want to write Joomla plugin to connect to user tables in database (one way). So on new user registration, user will be duplicated and stored also in second table (other script) And this is main goal. Things like updating on password change/delete etc. is later part.

Any ideas where I can find informations helping me to write plugin like that for Joomla 1.6? Where I can get user registration data etc?

I found this link here:

[Writing Joomla bridge - User plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960965/writing-joomla-bridge-user-plugin)

But what if you got some user_profiles entries to put in another table? I realy like to know how to solve this.

like adress, country, state information

Answer (score 0):

to get the information about user_profiles table use:

```
$vars1['entry_country_id'] = ($data['profile']['country']);
```