# Joomla: Can't make a plugin using onUserAfterSave work

Tags: php, plugins, joomla

Tried this half a dozen different ways and it's still not working. Joomla 1.7.3 on a local machine. The plugin does nothing, but it's not actually breaking anything - yet. As far as I can tell, the naming conventions are okay.

What I'm trying to do is insert a new row in a database table with the userid of a new user. The table has already been created and I checked the SQL query to make sure it worked.

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

// Import library dependencies
jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

class plgUserCNPluginUpdate extends JPlugin 
{
    function onUserAfterSave ($user, $isnew, $success, $msg) 
    {
        if (!$success) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        if ($isnew) 
        {
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $db->setQuery(
                'INSERT INTO `#__cnuser_cginfo`(`RecordID`,`UserID`) VALUES (NULL,'.(int) $user['id'].')'
            );
            $db->Query();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here? I've been looking around and any solution I try just doesn't work. It's in the right place and I can see it on the plugin manager screen. Hope someone can give me some advice on this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this on Joomla 1.6/7/2.5... and if you have it in the right place i.e. /plugins/user/cnpluginupdate/ wrap your db code in some error checking like this:

```
try
{
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $db->setQuery(
        'INSERT INTO `#__cnuser_cginfo`(`RecordID`,`UserID`)
         VALUES (NULL,'.(int) $user['id'].')'
    );

    if (!$db->query()) {
        throw new Exception($db->getErrorMsg());
    }        

    catch (JException $e)
    {
        $this->_subject->setError($e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

1. Currently you just return true no matter what happened so no error will be reported. Use a `try` as shown above to catch a possible error...
2. Are you sure it's making it past the `if (!$success)` - normally you would check all the inputs prior to doing any work and you would only return a `false` if your code encountered an error.

eg.

```
function onUserAfterSave($data, $isNew, $result, $error)
{
    $userId = JArrayHelper::getValue($data, 'id', 0, 'int');

    if ($userId && $result && isset($data['profile']) && (count($data['profile'])))
    {
      // then 'try' your code here
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but it has no effect. I wasn't sure how to add error checking code to the plugin, so that's great, but it's still doing nothing. At this point I'm wondering if I've got something wrong in the naming conventions - does case matter?

Comment: I've gone back over the naming stuff. The files are in /plugins/user/cnpluginupdate. The filename is plgusercnpluginupdate.php. The class is called plgUserCNPluginUpdate.

Comment: I'm testing this by adding users in the backend, not the frontend. Don't know if this makes a difference to the onUserAfterSave function.

Comment: For fuctions in PHP case doesn't actually count but it is good form to match the definition.  Let me have a think as to what else could be going on.

Comment: For reasons I can't work out, this solution here worked for me. I just copied the code and changed the database tables and it all worked exactly as expected. Still no idea why my code doesn't work though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960965/writing-joomla-bridge-user-plugin