# Can I have hooks in a Joomla component? How?

Tags: joomla, components, hook

I need to add a hook in `onUserAfterDelete` to when the admin deletes an user his customer info (managed by my component) goes away too.

How can I do that? Where I put the function?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to create a plugin, which will be independent of the component itself.

You need:

- manifest file
- plugin itself as a .php file - here you will implement the method `onUserAfterDelete`.

Some code to start with is already in another [related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5962267/766177)

Comment: There's no way to make this inside the component, I'm right?

Comment: It needs to be a plugin. But you can ship everything together in a package.

Comment: There are post save hooks. I don't know if there are post delete hooks everywhere but they are some places. So you can use those too. But plugins are great also.

Comment: Hello, i try with the code in the answer but only works if is in front end.. is there an aditional setting o code to get it working on backend'?

Comment: Please ask on Joomla.stackexchange.com